# Having some trouble using geometry manager .grid in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have some code here and I can't figure out why everything is getting smashed together. Also with the function I have, it isn't getting the actual text that I type into the Text widget. I'm a semi-newbie to Python and have been developing this game for a while.

```
def comments():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Comments")
    root.geometry("300x200+300+300")
    var = tk.IntVar()
    
    top_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="red", width=300, height=50)
    name_label = tk.Label(top_frame, text="Username", bg='red', fg="yellow", font=("arial, 17"), justify=LEFT)
    name_entry = tk.Entry(top_frame)
    comment_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="yellow", width=300, height=100, relief=GROOVE)
    comment_entry = tk.Text(comment_frame, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN, width=35, height=5)
    comment = comment_entry.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
    def save_comment():
        #if like_dislike == 0:
            #dislikes =+ 1
            #opinion = dislike
        #elif like_dislike == 1:
            #likes =+ 1
            #opinion = like
        
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        if now.hour > 12:
            hour = now.hour-12
            meridiem = 'pm'
        else:
            hour = now.hour
            meridiem = 'am'
            
        timestamp = str(now.month)+'/'+str(now.day)+'/'+str(now.year)+'\t'+str(hour)+':'+str(now.minute)+':'+str(now.second)
        with open(comments_file, 'a') as file:
            file.write(comment + timestamp + meridiem + '\r\n\n')
        exit_comments = tk.messagebox.askyesno('Exit', 'Return to About Page?')
        if exit_comments == True:
            root.destroy()
    like_dislike_frame = tk.Frame(root, relief=GROOVE, bg='green', width=300, height=50)
    #like_button = tk.Button(like_dislike_frame, text="Like").grid(row=2, sticky=W, padx="6px")
    #dislike_button = tk.Button(like_dislike_frame, text="Dislike").grid(row=2)
    like_button = tk.Checkbutton(like_dislike_frame, text="Like", font=("arial, 12"), onvalue=1,offvalue=0, variable=var, bg='green', fg='yellow')
    dislike_button = tk.Checkbutton(like_dislike_frame, text="Dislike", font=("arial, 12"), onvalue=1,offvalue=0, variable=var, bg='green', fg='yellow')
    submit_button = tk.Button(like_dislike_frame, text="Submit", command=save_comment)
    top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
    name_label.grid(row=0, sticky=W, padx="5px")
    name_entry.grid(row=0, sticky=E, padx="5px")
    comment_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)
    comment_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)
    like_dislike_frame.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)
    like_button.grid(row=2, sticky=W, padx="6px")
    dislike_button.grid(row=2, padx="6px")
    submit_button.grid(row=2, sticky=E)
    
    root.mainloop()**
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you haven't specified unique row/column numbers for most of your widgets.
Each frame has its own row/grid system so you can place a frame at row=0 column=0. If that frame then has two widget inside it, one to the right of the other you'd use row=0 column=0, row=0 column=1 for each widget respectively.

I looked at the like/dislike frame and specified a column for each of those

```
like_button.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=W, padx="6px")
dislike_button.grid(row=0,column=1, padx="6px")
submit_button.grid(row=0,column=2, sticky=E)
```

They now appear spaced out correctly.